# Override the value I have entered in conversational form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I m creating a chatbot (conversational-form) where i am asking for name of the customer, so if customer types "abcd", I will be saying..
hello.. "qwerty".. (i want to override the name entered by customer.. the value "querty" is depends on what customer types answer of the previous question and which will be coming from database.)  This is not my actual scenario but it will solve my problem

for now, i am able to get the value from database which is "querty". but unable to override the answer via javascript.

```
      <form id="cf-form" method="post">
     <fieldset>
       <input required cf-questions="Help us with your name and let’s take this chat ahead." type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" id="name" cf-input-placeholder="Enter your Name" />
      </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <input required cf-questions="Hello, {previous-answer}, whats your mobile number." type="number" class="form-control" name="number" id="number" cf-input-placeholder="Select your Mobile Number" />
    </fieldset>   
</form>
```

So here, {previous answer} getting the value i have entered previously, but i am trying to overrride the value i want to get it from database based on previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ?

> jQuery("#number").attr('cf-questions',"Test")